# Deadlock when insert on duplicate key update sql using on multi unique key

Tags: mysql, deadlock

Is sql like insert ... on duplicate key update will generate gap locks on every unique key index/primary key, disordered, when the row is not in table?

I found that when using multi transactions to execute insert on duplicate key update sql on table with more than one unique key may cause deadlock.

My table was like:

```
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                
| test | CREATE TABLE `test1` (
  `c1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `c2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`c1`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uk` (`c2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

After the deadlock arise，I got engine innodb status:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2018-12-06 20:01:57 0x70000ee06000
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2219555, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 6686, OS thread handle 123145569476608, query id 6114936 localhost 127.0.0.1 root update
INSERT INTO test1 (`c1`, `c2`, `c3`) VALUES (15538, 1213457428, 30) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `c3` = VALUES(`c3`)
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 65 page no 29 n bits 848 index cc of table `compare_db`.`test1` trx id 2219555 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 749 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex c88c97bb; asc     ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80002c42; asc   ,B;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2219538, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1 4 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 6631, OS thread handle 123145551896576, query id 6114889 localhost 127.0.0.1 root update
INSERT INTO test1 (`c1`, `c2`, `c3`) VALUES (535, 1215380840, 30) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `c3` = VALUES(`c3`)
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 65 page no 29 n bits 840 index cc of table `compare_db`.`test1` trx id 2219538 lock_mode X locks gap before rec
Record lock, heap no 749 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex c88c97bb; asc     ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80002c42; asc   ,B;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 65 page no 29 n bits 848 index cc of table `compare_db`.`test1` trx id 2219538 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 749 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex c88c97bb; asc     ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80002c42; asc   ,B;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

It would be just fine when insert directly.
So I was thinking, is that because the two session both happened to locked gap (a, b) on uk, and (c, d) on primary key when deadlock arose, but with different order.
Is anyone knows the real reason?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I haven't got the root cause. I've changed my sql to "select ... for update; update ...".